# Spring Batch Itemreader pass same Object twice to Itemprocessor

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have Spring batch with partition. The gridSize is 10, so it will spawn 10 threads. Everything is default Bean singleton. TaskExeutor has max 15, core pool 10.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public RepositoryItemReader<CustomObject> reader(${executorContext[from]} from, ${executorContext[to], ${executorContext[partitonId]) {
    LOG.info("Partition ID: {} will process row from: {}  to: {}", partitionId, from, to);
    //here has the right output, say 1 to 10, 10 to 20, include from, exclude to
    RepositoryItemReader reader = new RepositoryItemReader();
    reader.setRepository(objectRepo);
    reader.setMethod("findByProcessedFromAndTo");
    //from here I pass in from and to to do the partition
    //omit sorts, pageSize,  params
    reader.setSaveState(false);
    return reader;
}
```

Here is the reader, this reader will  return 4 rows in DB. CustomObject 1 to 4.

```
@Bean
public class processor implements ItemProcessor() {
   @override
   public Object process(customObject) {
       logger.info(customObject.getId());
       //logic
   }
}

@Bean
Step processStep(){
    //chunk 1
    //item reader
    //item processor
    //item writer
    //build
}

Step partitionStep {
    //partion with gridSize 10,
    //processStep
    //taskExecutor
}

Partition  {
    int start = 1;
    int range = totalCount/gridSize + 1;
    for(i to gridSize){
        ExecutionContext context = New ExecutionContext();
       context.put("from",start);
       context.put("to", start*range);
       start += range;
       context.put("partitionId", i); 
       map.put(PARTITION_KEY, context);      
    }
    return map;
}
```

The sample Query:

```
select * from Table where rownum >=:from and rownum < :to;
```

The Setup is very simple. Just a batch process with partition gridsize 10.

When I run it, Item reader gets 4 records which is correct. But when reader pass the data to item processor, I got such log, I am making number up.

```
Thread 2 processing Object Id: 11 //row 10 to 20
Thread 1 processing Object Id: 1 //row  1 to 10
Thread 4 processing Object Id: 31 //row  30 to 40
Thread 6 processing Object Id: 51 //row  50 to 60
```

Since I implementate the partition and do the partition in the query. Now all thread should process the partitioned set and should not process the duplicate record,  but still I got the same issue, some thread will process the duplicate record.

```
Thread 9 processing Object ID:2
Thread 3 processing Object ID:4
and so on
```

And when the whole job finishes, there will be unprocessed records in db.

Did I missing something, need some help.

Comment: How did you partition data? What is your partitioner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The expected behavior is that ItemReader should only pass these 4 data to 4 thread

This is what you would expect for a multi-threaded step, not a partitioned step.

For a partitioned step, setting the grid size is not sufficient. You need to define partitions upfront with a `Partitioner` and set it on the master step so that each worker step processes one partition. Without specifying a partitioner, Spring Batch can not know how to partition items and your reader will be used for all (undefined) partitions, reading the whole data set multiple times.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother. I updated my questions. I make itemreader stepScope to inject the execution context from partition. Item processor and item writer are still singleton. The whole  idea  is that each thread should process its own partitioned set of data.